# Miller-Rabin prime test

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes

I have an implementation of the [Miller-Rabin prime test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), coded in Python 3.

I want to use that as a comparison to a prime test which I coded myself.
Unfortunately I have no idea how "fast" the Miller-Rabin test should be on my machine.

With my code I can test the number n = 2¹⁰⁰⁰⁰+1 in less than 4 seconds. But I don't know whether this is a good time.

The implemented version of gmpy2 is much much faster.
But I think it's not a good comparison because my own test is written in python and gmpy2 is written in C, I suppose.

```py
import gmpy2
import random
import time

def rab_test(N, rounds = 40):
    if N in [2, 3]:
        return True
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return False
    n = N // 2
    t = 1
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
        t += 1
    for _ in range(0, rounds):
        a = random.randrange(2, N-1)
        u = gmpy2.powmod(a, n, N)
        if u == 1 or N-u == 1:
            return True
        for k in range(1, t):
            u = gmpy2.powmod(u, 2, N)
            if N-u == 1:
                return True
    return False
```

I tested 2²⁰⁰⁰+1 and got the result after 0.5 seconds.
For 10²⁰⁰⁰+1, it needed 4.8 seconds

```py
start = time.time()
print(rab_test(2**2000+1))
print(time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
print(rab_test(10**2000+1))
print(time.time() - start)
```

For (2⁵⁰⁰¹+1)*2¹⁰⁰⁰⁰+1, it needed exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: If you want to use it as the baseline to compare another algorithm, then the performance relative to a C implementation isn't important, I think - only how well your own tests scales against it.

Answer (score 3):

## cite your reference

As written, the OP code gives me little reason to
believe it is a faithful implementation of
[Miller's paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/800116.803773)
nor of [wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)
retelling of it.

Using an opaque identifier like `u` *can* be very
helpful to someone seeking to understand your implementation,
when it matches a variable from your cited reference.
You cited wikipedia, yet invented new names
unrelated to the variable names used there.
This fails to inspire confidence in the implementation.

## wrong name

`def rab_test` might be a good way to introduce
the analysis of a rabies test, but in this context
it is less helpful than e.g. `is_a_miller_rabin_prime()`.
As stated it's unclear how we should interpret a `True` result
until we examine some special cases in the code.

```
    n = N // 2
```

That would be an unfortunate choice of identifiers
even if some cited author used two different N's to represent
two different quantities.
The [pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
advice on choosing names is sometimes at variance with
long established mathematical conventions.
Here, I would ask you to please at least choose names
that we could recite over the telephone when discussing
details with a colleague, without resorting to
verbose descriptions of "no not that N, the other N in Fraktur font"
or whatever the original naming motivation was.

## docstring

The OP source code has no comments of any kind.
A """docstring""" would be an excellent place
to offer one or more literature citations.

## use tqdm

Performance is of interest for this code,
which can take some seconds to produce a result.
You may find it convenient to
[instrument](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm)
the outer loop with a progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
...
    for _ in tqdm(range(0, rounds)):
```

As you try different input values and code variations
this lets you quickly assess the cost of each round.

Consider using numpy to compute the `gmpy2.powmod(u, 2, N)`
recurrence relation as a single vector of `t` objects,
in the interest of speed.

Answer (score 1):

### Documentation

You could add documentation at the top of your file to state the purpose
of the code, for example:

```
'''
The Miller-Rabin prime test is an algorithm which determines
whether a given number is likely to be prime (from Wikipedia).
'''
```

Your function could have a docstring which describes valid inputs
and the return value.

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few style issues.

Variable `k` is unused in this line:

```
    for k in range(1, t):
```

You can use `_` as you did in your other `for` loop.

### Naming

It is common for functions that return a boolean value to have
an `is_` prefix.  For example, instead of `rab_test`, consider
naming the function something like `is_likely_prime`.

Most of the variable names are not very meaningful (`a`, `t`, `u`, etc.).
Consider giving them longer, more meaningful names, or at least add
comments describing what they refer to.  If they are based on an equation,
you can add a reference to some external documentation.

### Simple

This could be simplified:

```
    n = n // 2
```

as:

```
    n //= 2
```

### Performance

As you mentioned, the `gmpy2` library your code uses is implemented in C.
This means you are already potentially taking advantage of fast code.

### Test code

I added a loop around your calls to make it easier for others to
add more examples:

```
for n in [2**2000+1, 10**2000+1]:
    start = time.time()
    print(rab_test(n))
    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Thank you, there are helpful hints and I will take note of them. Nevertheless, my actual question is not answered. I was wondering whether it is meaningful to compare my test (written in python) to an implementation of the miller-rabin written in C.

Comment: @Lereu: You're welcome.  Since you are a new user, another way to say "thanks" for those who answered your question [is to upvote/accept](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)